# How to count through several lists contained in a groupby object and add counts together for every value in the lists of that group

Tags: python, list, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I have the following problem. I have a dataframe that I `groupby` a column, then make a `list` of the `strings` contained in the other column. Since it is grouped, I have several lists from several columns in a group. Now I want to go through every list in a group and count the values contained in those lists. Finally, for every value I make a new column and want it to contain the total counts of the value from every list in that group. Here is my exemplary dataframe:

```
df1:
      Column1 Column2   
    0   L17      a,b,c,d,e
    1   L7       a,b,c
    2   L6       a,b,f
    3   L6       a,b,e
```

What I want to get out is:

```
   Column1  Column2     a   b   c   d   e   f   h
0   L17      a,b,c,d,e  1   1   1   1   1   nan nan
1   L7       a,b,c      1   1   1   nan nan nan nan
2   L6       a,b,f      2   2   nan nan 1   1   nan
```

What I have coded so far is:

```
def NewCols(x):
    for key, group in UngroupedResGenesLineage.groupby('Column1'):
        for item, frame in group['Column2'].iteritems():
            Genes = frame.split(',')
            counter = collections.Counter(Genes)
            for value in Genes:
                string = value
                x[string] = sum(counter.values())
    return x

X = df1.groupby('Column1').apply(NewCols)
```

The code works in so far that I get my new columns and lists of all values contained in a group. The problem is that they all are filled with the same values, which is definitly not correct. I just recently discovered `Counter` and thought it might be useful, but I can't find out how to count all values in all `frame` lists ('Genes' in the code) for a group and add the counts together for each value in the list.

Does someone have an idea how I should change my code to achieve what I want? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why for `L6` `e` does not have `1` ? And in the result you still need `Column2` ?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. In `L6` `e` is supposed to have `1`, fixed it in the question. Yes, `Column2` should remain in the data frame.

Comment: For L6 don't you want the combination of Column2 from both rows?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas str.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.get_dummies.html)

```
In[3]: cntr = df.Column2.str.get_dummies(',').groupby(df.Column1).sum()
In[4]: print cntr
         a  b  c  d  e  f
Column1                  
L17      1  1  1  1  1  0
L6       2  2  0  0  1  1
L7       1  1  1  0  0  0
```

Now, you can join this back with the original dataframe and replace the 0 with nan.

```
In[5]: x = pd.merge(df.drop_duplicates('Column1'), cntr.replace(0, pd.np.nan).reset_index())
In[6]: print x

  Column1    Column2  a  b   c   d   e   f
0     L17  a,b,c,d,e  1  1   1   1   1 NaN
1      L7      a,b,c  1  1   1 NaN NaN NaN
2      L6      a,b,f  2  2 NaN NaN   1   1
```

Comment: Easy and fast, thank you! I'll read up on the `.get_dummies` function.

Comment: Wait, actually it does not work properly..I something goes wrong in the merge. I guess it has to do with the indexes, since the index of cntr is `Column1` and the other is `int64`. I'll research how to add an `int64` index to the cntr dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

If in the resulting DataFrame, you want the combination (unique elements) from all rows of `Column2` . Then you can use the following function which uses Counter to count all the elements and creates new columns from the elements in Column2. Example -

```
def func(row):
    slist = np.array(row['Column2'].str.split(',').tolist()).flatten()
    count = Counter(slist)
    res = pd.Series()
    res['Column2'] = ','.join(sorted(count))
    for key,val in count.items():
        res[key] = val
    return pd.DataFrame(res).T
```

Then you can group and then reset index . Example -

```
result = df.groupby('Column1').apply(func).reset_index().drop('level_1',axis=1)
```

---

Demo -

```
In [130]: def func(row):
   .....:     slist = np.array(row['Column2'].str.split(',').tolist()).flatten()
   .....:     count = Counter(slist)
   .....:     res = pd.Series()
   .....:     res['Column2'] = ','.join(sorted(count))
   .....:     for key,val in count.items():
   .....:         res[key] = val
   .....:     return pd.DataFrame(res).T
   .....:

In [131]: df
Out[131]:
  Column1    Column2
0     L17  a,b,c,d,e
1      L7      a,b,c
2      L6      a,b,f
3      L6      a,b,e

In [135]: df.groupby('Column1').apply(func).reset_index().drop('level_1',axis=1)
Out[135]:
  Column1    Column2  a  b    c    d    e    f
0     L17  a,b,c,d,e  1  1    1    1    1  NaN
1      L6    a,b,e,f  2  2  NaN  NaN    1    1
2      L7      a,b,c  1  1    1  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: looks very smooth, but actually when I try running it I get: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Any idea what could cause that error?

Comment: It begins at the line where I start the df.groupby and eventually narrows down to `553                 self_get = self.get
    554                 for elem in iterable:
--> 555                     self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
    556         if kwds:
    557             self.update(kwds)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: That does not seem like from the code I posted , most probably its your own code ?

Comment: Nope, it's from your code. I would post the whole error message but it is too lnog to put into a comment... `---> 11 UngroupedResGenesLineage.groupby('Lineage').apply(func).reset_index().drop('level_1',axis=1)

C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    669         # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
    670         with option_context('mode.chained_assignment',None):
--> 671             return self._python_apply_general(f)
    672 
    673     def _python_apply_general(self, f):` would be a part if it helps..

Comment: Maybe you can take a screenshot and upload that and link to it

Comment: To where could I upload it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92504/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-sequence-hard).